# how to parse self closing tag in xml file

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iphone application in which I am consuming a webservice.
So i am parsing the XML file data. any idea about how to parse self closing tag
like: State/ and how to read data of self tag like: Contact Email="abc@anc.com" Name="PhD" Phone="123-521-3388" Source="location"/

I am parsing xml file using NSXMLPARSER class methods and library

Thanks,

Comment: Like?

What are you using to parse the tag? I hope it's an XML library.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample XML data

```
<Contact Email="abc@anc.com" Name="PhD" Phone="123-521-3388" Source="location"/>
```

is equivalent to

```
<Contact Email="abc@anc.com" Name="PhD" Phone="123-521-3388" Source="location"></Contact>
```

and should be parsed by any XML parser.

Comment: <Contact Email="abc@anc.com" Name="PhD" Phone="123-521-3388" Source="location"/>
is this equivalent or not to

<Contact Email="abc@anc.com" Name="PhD" Phone="123-521-3388" Source="location"></Contact>

first one is self closing tag,
when i parse this i got a string like "\n     ".

so how can i read  EMAIL, NAME PHONE ??

Comment: Email, Name, Phone and Source are XML "attributes". To use the Mac OS NSXMLParser class to get attributes, you need to give the NSXMLParser an NSXMLParserDelegate that looks at the attributes passed to the [parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:) method.

Comment: By the way, the attributes passed to that method are an NSDictionary, see [the NSDictionary discussion here.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html)